# Files Not Saving to Laravel 9 Public Directory

Tags: php, laravel

I'm generating PDF documents on the fly using [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) and saving it to the public directory.  Works great locally, but on a production Digital Ocean server, the file won't save to the public directory.  In my code below at the `->saveAs...`, the '`docs/reg-forms/'` are directories within public.

```
...
$pdf = new Pdf('/docs/ax_reg_form.pdf');
$result = $pdf->fillForm([
    'email' => $this->usercar->user->email,
    'date' => $this->usercar->created_at,
    ...
])
    ->needAppearances()
    ->saveAs('docs/reg-forms/'.$this->usercar->user->id.'_'.strtolower($this->usercar->user->first_name).'_'.strtolower($this->usercar->user->last_name).'_'.'car_class.pdf');


session()->flash('url', '/docs/reg-forms/'.$this->usercar->user->id.'_'.strtolower($this->usercar->user->first_name).'_'.strtolower($this->usercar->user->last_name).'_'.'car_class.pdf');

return redirect()->route('usercar.show', $this->usercar->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap with **public_path** helper

```
public_path('docs/reg-forms/');
```

and check if the path exists

```
if (!file_exists(public_path('docs/reg-forms/'))) {
    mkdir(public_path('docs/reg-forms/'), 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: adding `public_path` works locally but still not in production

Comment: path from /public exists? try to execute mkdir(public_path('docs/reg-forms/'),0777,true);